# Convert nested type in C# using delegates / LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, generics

How can I convert a `List<List<string>>` to a `List<string[]>` in C# in a concise way using delegates/LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<List<string>> listOfLists = new List<List<string>>();

listOfLists.Add(new List<string>(){ "bla", "foo", "bar"});
listOfLists.Add(new List<string>() { "alfa", "beta", "gama" });
listOfLists.Add(new List<string>() { "earth", "moon", "sun" });
listOfLists.Add(new List<string>() { "cat", "dog", "owl" });

List<string[]> listOfArrays = new List<string[]>();

listOfArrays = listOfLists.Select(l => l.ToArray()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe this will do it:

```
var result = (from list in listOfLists select list.ToArray()).ToList()
```

Comment: or `var result = listOfList.Select(list => list.ToArray()).ToList()`, which is just the other way of writing it.

Comment: i've been doing it this way all the time

Answer (score 3):

```
var lists = new List<List<string>>();
List<string[]> arrays = lists.ConvertAll(l => l.ToArray());
```